# Extrair Chave Result

Tags: php

**Tenho esta função .......**

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://wss........N.asmx?wsdl');
$funcao = 'ConsultarUsuario';
$argumentos = array($funcao => array(
    'ChaveUsuario' => 'U10..........921',
    'aplicativo' => 'S..........ob',
    'RotaDatabase' => 'C:\Ine......................s\database.mdb'
    ));
$resultado = $client->__soapCall($funcao, $argumentos);
echo ' RESPOSTA = ';
print_r($resultado);
```

**Minha resposta no browser**

```
RESPOSTA = stdClass Object ( [ConsultarUsuarioResult] => stdClass Object ( [string] => Array ( [0] => Usuário Registrado [1] => User Teste Mob1 [2] => U10SEG0721 [3] => 10/07/2017 03:00:00 [4] => 10/08/2017 03:00:00 [5] => Ativo [6] => Paulo R Maia [7] => 55555555555555 [8] => endereço teste [9] => 77 [10] => casa [11] => bairro teste [12] => cidade teste [13] => sp [14] => 55555555 [15] => 55555555555 [16] => teste@hotmail.com [17] => Sistema [18] => 99 [19] => Testando [20] => 1 ) ) )
```

Preciso extrair valores de algumas destas chaves e armazenar em $variaveis

estou tentando assim,   mas sem exito.

**Mas o meu Problema mesmo , é que não consigo extrair os valores das chaves,  para armazenar em variáveis**

**Tentativas .......**

```
$resultado->ConsultarUsuarioResult[6];
echo $resultado;
```

**Nem Assim.........**

```
$valorExtraido = $resultado->ConsultarUsuarioResult[6];
echo $valorExtraido;
```

.
.
.
Qual seria a solução  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma correta de utilizar seria:

```
$resultado->ConsultarUsuarioResult->string[0]
```

Pois pelo `print_r` que mostrou vemos que tem um objeto:

```
RESPOSTA = stdClass Object (
```

Que depois tem outro objeto para a propriedade `ConsultarUsuarioResult`:

```
[ConsultarUsuarioResult] => stdClass Object (
```

Em que esse objeto tem uma propriedade chamada `string` que é um `Array`:

```
( [string] => Array (
```

Coloquei [online um exemplo que constrói um objeto idêntico ao que tem e depois extrai o respetivo valor](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5ad02ab4ef6026f3b4eb940d97b24390b924dda9)

Comment: RESOLVIDO !   Obrigado , Isac